# Hbase: Getting a row key based on a column qualifier value

Tags: filter, mapreduce, hbase

I have hbase table, column family, column qualifier and the value. Need to get rowkey. I have tried SingleColumnValueFilter but it took around 2 hours to scan entire table as my table contains billions of records. I need a better approach which gives **rowkey** in minutes than hours. Please help me out

Below is my code:

```
SingleColumnValueFilter colValFilter = new SingleColumnValueFilter(Bytes.toBytes(<CF>),
   Bytes.toBytes(<CQ>), CompareFilter.CompareOp.EQUAL,
   new BinaryComparator(Bytes.toBytes(<VALUE>)));
```

Comment: You want to do it once or you will do it now and then? As in different scenario, the solution is different, a map-reduce job is enough for the first and a secondary index is needed for the second.

Comment: I want it to be more robust. Use multiple times. As I am new to Hadoop, please suggest me how to work with secondary index.

Comment: There is a solution about secondary index using apache phoenix,  https://phoenix.apache.org/secondary_indexing.html, https://phoenix.apache.org/faq.html#How_I_map_Phoenix_table_to_an_existing_HBase_table these two links can help you. Please pay attention that secondary index will cost you both space and compute.

Comment: are you still looking for solution? i test phoenix myself, and it seems if you want to use secondary index, you have to use phoenix apis if you want to update your index dynamically .  i don't think that's a good solution. i'm trying to use coprocessor to achieve this, may answer the question later :)